# Android Application class not calling onCreate with alternate product flavor

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I set a breakpoint in my `MyAppApplication.onCreate()` method.  It gets hit with 1 product flavor but not the other.  This is the only breakpoint that doesn't get hit.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the applicationId, but I'm not understanding why,

build.gradle

```
productFlavors {
    prod { //the flavor that works
        applicationId 'com.my.app'
        versionName "1.2.3"
    }
    staging { //the flavor that doesnt
        applicationId 'com.my.app.staging'
        versionName "1.2.3-staging"
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.app">
    ...
    <application android:name="com.my.app.MyAppApplication"
    ...
```

I've tried replacing the manifest package to ${applicationId}, but that gives me an error.  The package names don't change with the flavor, only the appliationId.  From what I understand, the package name in manifest gets swapped out by gradle during build time anyway.

Comment: if you set applicationId  in gradle ,the applicationId  in Manifest dones't work。

Comment: Use application android:name=".MyAppApplication"

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what was happening bug they are working as of last night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to repro what went wrong for you, here're some guidance how to make your app multi-flavourable, so I hope you'll find the missing/wrong step by following it.

I've created a test project with package: klogi.com.flavourapp:

1. In app's module, `build.gradle` add:

   ```
   productFlavors {
       production {
           applicationId "klogi.com.flavourapp"
       }

       staging {
           applicationId "klogi.com.flavourapp.staging"
       }
   }
   ```
2. To show flavour effect, I'll change name of app in the `Toolbar`. To do it, in `FlavourApp\app\src` directory create directory `staging\res\values` and `strings.xml` file inside:

   [image]

   Then the values from this `FlavourApp\app\src\staging\res\values\strings.xml` will override default `FlavourApp\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml`.
3. Last step is to create `Application`'s extension:

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends Application {

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi " + BuildConfig.FLAVOR, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   }
   ```

   and assign it in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

   ```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="klogi.com.flavourapp">
       <application
           android:name=".MyApplication"
           android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
           <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>
       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```

   I checked, there's no difference between `android:name="klogi.com.flavourapp.MyApplication"` and `android:name=".MyApplication"` , but I still think the second one is better.

Here's the result:

[image][image]

And the test project you can find: **[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6cqn4aff44fznkf/FlavourApp.zip?dl=0)**;

I hope, it helps